# Error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I keep getting this error in my code.

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined` I have read some other posts with a similar error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined of null` and I have tried some of the methods suggested, but nothing seems to change.

It seems to point to this line `document.getElementsByClassName("demo")[i].innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;` I don't understan why as before I added the loop, it worked fine.

**My Code**

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<!--#include file="../Connections/DVerto.asp" -->
<%
Dim Recordset1
Dim Recordset1_cmd
Dim Recordset1_numRows

Set Recordset1_cmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
Recordset1_cmd.ActiveConnection = MM_DVerto_STRING
Recordset1_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Part_Number FROM dbo.Stock_Header WHERE Part_Number like '84%'" 
Recordset1_cmd.Prepared = true

Set Recordset1 = Recordset1_cmd.Execute
Recordset1_numRows = 0
%>
<%
Dim Repeat1__numRows
Dim Repeat1__index

Repeat1__numRows = 10
Repeat1__index = 0
Recordset1_numRows = Recordset1_numRows + Repeat1__numRows
%>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body onLoad="loadDoc()">
<table width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
  <% 
While ((Repeat1__numRows <> 0) AND (NOT Recordset1.EOF)) 
%>
  <tr>
    <td class="prodref"><%=(Recordset1.Fields.Item("Part_Number").Value)%></td>
    <td class="demo">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <% 
  Repeat1__index=Repeat1__index+1
  Repeat1__numRows=Repeat1__numRows-1
  Recordset1.MoveNext()
Wend
%>
</table>
<script>
var a = document.getElementsByClassName("prodref").length;
var i = 0;
for (i; i < a; i++) {
    loadDoc();
}
function loadDoc() {
    var a = document.getElementsByClassName("prodref");
    a[i] = document.getElementsByClassName("prodref").innerHTML;
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementsByClassName("demo")[i].innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "data.asp?prodref="+a[i].innerHTML, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
<%
Recordset1.Close()
Set Recordset1 = Nothing
%>
```

Comment: Are you use there is a class called "demo"?

Comment: @LJa Yes, one of my table cells has a class of `demo` - `<td class="demo"></td>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `i` to the function because the loop is complete by the time the AJAX requests return.

```
var prodref = document.getElementsByClassName("prodref");
var demo = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
var i = 0;
var a = prodref.length;

for (i; i < a; i++) {
    loadDoc(i);
}

function loadDoc(i) {
  console.log("creating loadDoc() call for", i);

  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    console.log("callback invoked for", i, "with state:", xhttp.readyState);

    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      console.log("setting .innerHTML for", i, "to:", xhttp.responseText);
      demo[i].innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
  };

  xhttp.open("GET", "data.asp?prodref="+prodref[i].innerHTML, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

Now there's an `i` variable local to each separate invocation of `loadDoc` and the callback function you create in that function will close over that local `i`.

This is a *closure*.

I also cached your DOM selections. You don't need to keep fetching the nodes over and over unless you think they will change.

Comment: Thanks for this. It works but it is acting a little eratic. Sometime it returns results for 2 out of 4 rows, then 3 or 4 out of 4. Also it sometimes misses a row? Any suggestions?

Comment: @JonathanGriffin: You'll want to do some debugging by adding some `console.log()` calls at various points in your code to see what is happening and when. For example, see if the callback is invoked for each item and then see if the `if` condition gets invoked. I'll add some examples to the answer.

Comment: also, if possible, it's better design to send only one request and tell it how many results you want. JSON is a common format to send collections of data.

Comment: Thanks @squint I will take a look at what you have suggested

Answer (score 1):

You're making an asynchronous request so the variable *i* will not be what you expect when the *onreadystatechange* function is called.

try this instead:

```
...
for (i; i < a; i++) {
    loadDoc(i);
}

function loadDoc(i) {
...
```